# How can I solve a dynamic algebraic equation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, eval

If I have a formula in a string `x = y + (10/2) * 6` (it’s dynamic, so not necessarily that) and I know that `x = 5`. How can I calculate the value to `y`?

Comment: Is the formula string *always* that? Or is it dynamic?

Comment: @pjs - yes for simple calculation it will be linear

Answer (score 3):

You can use a parser like [dentaku](https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku)

```
require 'dentaku'

calculator = Dentaku::Calculator.new
calculator.evaluate('10 * 2')
# => 20
calculator.evaluate('kiwi + 5', :kiwi => 2)
# => 7
```

Comment: I don't think this will solve my problem I need to rearrange the equation so that I can calculate the value of the equation. And yes I can calculate the equations using the parsers like `dentaku`.

Comment: But the I have the equation like mentioned above in question `x = y + (10/2) * 6` and I have value of variable `x` I need to calculate the value of `y` here. hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 2):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/) has a free (with signup) API. Someone has even [made a gem](https://github.com/cldwalker/wolfram) out of it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [calculus](https://github.com/avsej/)

```
001:0> require 'calculus'
true
002:0> exp = Calculus::Expression.new("2 + 3 * x")
#<Expression:f46e77a9377ed2d5a9da768496a7e1c20be51bfe postfix_notation=[2, 3, "x", :mul, :plus] variables={"x"=>nil}>
003:0> exp.postfix_notation
[2, 3, "x", :mul, :plus]
004:0> exp.abstract_syntax_tree
[:plus, 2, [:mul, 3, "x"]]
005:0> exp.variables
["x"]
006:0> exp.unbound_variables
["x"]
007:0> exp["x"] = 5
5
008:0> exp.unbound_variables
[]
009:0> exp.calculate
17
```

Comment: This is also one of the parser but doesn't solve my problem. It can only evaluate the given equations using the bounded variable values. But cannot provide the way to rearrange the equation or can solve the equation for non bounded variable like in my case is `y` and bounded variable is `x`